# mapView calloutAccessoryControlTapped, how to know who launched it?

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm working on a project with a map, there are some annotations whose views have a detail button.

Those annotations are created in a for loop where I get data in JSON format, and for every element an annotation is created.
However there's no direct correlation between Annotations (or AnnotationViews) and those elements.

```
...
anView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
...

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openInfo", sender: control)
    }
```

I understand that this button calls the mapView function with calloutAccessoryControlTapped, and passes the AnnotationView.

The problem is that, even if I know the AnnotationView that called the segue, I don't know whose this responds to.
Is there any way to save some informations in the AnnotationView? I mean, so that every instance of AnnotationView has an ID that can relate to the data i received?

Any other idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the selected annotation from:

```
let selectedAnnotation = view.annotation as! CustomAnnotation // See structure below.
```

And if you have a data source which you want to access, it's recommended to create a custom object for your `MKAnnotation`s that contain some reference to your data source, like an identifier. And then set:

```
selectedId = selectedAnnotation.id
performSegueWithIdentifier("openInfo", sender: control)
```

And in your `prepareForSegue` pass the `selectedId` to the receiving view controller.

**EDIT**: Your annotation class could look something like this:

```
class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var subtitle: String?

    var id: Int

    init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, subtitle: String, id: Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.subtitle = subtitle

        self.id = id
    }
}
```